# Data Envelopment Analysis implementation in Python Gurobi

Tags: python, gurobi

[Attached is the DEA notes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1BEX.jpg)

Below is the code I am having so far. When I run it, I got this error 
line 33, in 
    m.addConstr(quicksum([L[i]*Xi[i][j] for j in range(n1) if i <= j])-(theta*X0[k][j] for j in range(len(Xi))) <= 0,'Xi%d' % (i))

File "linexpr.pxi", line 429, in gurobipy.LinExpr.**sub** (../../src/python/gurobipy.c:32250)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'generator'

```
from gurobipy import *

X0 =[[5,14],\
    [8,15],\
    [7,12]]

Xi = list(map(list, zip(*X0)))

Y0 =[[9,4,16],\
    [5,7,10],\
    [4,9,13]]

Yi = list(map(list, zip(*Y0)))    

n1= len(X0)
n2= len(Yi)

m = Model("DEA")

#set up variables
theta = m.addVar(obj=1)#,vtype=GRB.SEMIINT,name='theta')

L = {}
for i in range(n1):
    L[i] = m.addVar(obj=0,vtype=GRB.SEMIINT, lb=0,name='L%d' % i)

m.update() 

#set up constraints
k = 0
for i in range(n1):
    m.addConstr(quicksum([L[i]*Xi[i][j] for j in range(n1) if i <= j])-(theta*X0[k][j] for j in range(len(Xi))) <= 0,'Xi%d' % (i))

for i in range(n2):
    m.addConstr(quicksum([L[i]*Yi[i][j] for j in range(n1) if i <= j]) >= Y0[k][i], 'Yi%d' % (i))

m.optimize()

m.write('DEA.lp')

# Print solution
if m.status == GRB.status.OPTIMAL:
    print ('\nOptimal flows:')
    for v in m.getVars():
        if v.X > 0:
            print( '%6s = %4.1f' % (v.VarName, v.X))
    print()
    print( 'Objective Value:', m.ObjVal)

else:
    print ('Bummer ',m.status)
```

Comment: Im just trying to do DEA for DMU 1

Comment: There are multiple errors in your code. Try debugging it line by line, and call `m.write("mymodel.lp")` to view the algebraic representation of your model.